# Parsing RAW camera images

Tags: image, image-processing, camera, tiff

Does parsing of a RAW camera image yield all the necessary informations to create a viewable picture from it?

More specifically, is it possible to obtain informations like sensor layout, crop position and size, ... just from the RAW file?

I'm asking because in the case of crop, there is `ActiveArea` TIFF tag but it seems it is not always available. Also, I see that RAW conversion software seem to always include a hand-crafted database of attributes like black-point, sensor pattern so I was wondering whether that is some kind of optimisation or that all the required information is simply not there in the RAW?

Comment: Are you asking about the DNG format, or "camera RAW" formats in general? In the latter case, the question is open-ended...

Comment: @haraldK RAW in general. It is not open-ended: if most of the time (i.e. major vendors) the TIFF alone would not be sufficient that would answer my question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that *most of the time* you have enough information available to create *a viewable picture* from the formats of what I consider *major vendors*. But I am very unsure of the value of such an answer...

Comment: Even, most of the time, there's a large JPEG "preview" in the RAW file. Would it be sufficient to view that?

Comment: @haraldK Unfortunately no, I would like to "develop" the RAW myself.